# Extending an abstract SAM class with parameters in Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to extend an abstract class in Java using a Javascript function. For example, `test/A.java`:

```
package test;

public class A {
    public A(String s) {}

    public abstract void go(Object a);
}
```

and `test.js`:

```
var myA = new Packages.test.A(function f(a) { print('Calling with '+a); }, 'hello');
```

Evaluating the line above causes the error `Can not create new object with constructor test.A with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures`, but the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147269) seems to suggest that this method is a valid means of instantiating a subclass:

> If the abstract class has a single abstract method (a SAM type), then instead of passing a JavaScript object to the constructor, you can pass the function that implements the method. The following example shows how you can simplify the syntax when using a SAM type:
>
> ```
> var task = new TimerTask(function() { print("Hello World!") });
> ```
>
> Whichever syntax you choose, if you need to invoke a constructor with arguments, you can specify the arguments after the implementation object or function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function argument comes last, not first. The documentation is in error and will need to be fixed; I raised [an issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147605) for it. Thanks for pointing this out.

`var myA = new Packages.test.A('hello', function f(a) { print('Calling with '+a); });`

should work.